# Why isn't my ref object being updated when my reactive state changes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In the following code I have a `reactive` state object in one file. My UI updates correctly whenever this object changes.

However, I added a PrimeVue menu component and the `visible` property on of my menu item isn't changing when the `signedIn` state changes. Why isn't it changing please?  My state is `reactive` and my `menuItems` are in a `ref`, so surely both those objects are reactive and should update the UI?

I've had to resort to putting a watch on my state, which is not elegant.

`State.ts`

```js
export const state: types.State = reactive(
{
    journal: {entries:[], databaseSchemaVersion: 0},
    user: {isSignedIn: false}
});
```

`Menu.ts`

```js
<!-- HTML ----------------------------------------------------->
<template>
    <PVMenu ref="menu" id="overlay_menu" :model="menuItems" :popup="true" />
</template>

<!-- JS ------------------------------------------------------->
<script setup lang="ts">

const menu = ref();
const menuItems = ref([
    {
        label: messages.Signout,
        icon: 'fa fa-right-from-bracket',
        visible: state.state.user.isSignedIn, //does not update :(
        command: () =>
        {
            state.setDropboxToken('');
        }
    }
]);

//yuck, but it works
watch(() => state.state.user.isSignedIn, (newValue) => {
    menuItems.value.filter(item => item.label === messages.Signout)[0].visible = newValue;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Inside the `ref` you're constructing a new object. Plain objects are not reactive. When you're making the object you're assigning to one of its props the current value of a reactive object, but the object prop does not maintain the reactivity of the source. If you want to maintain reactivity, use a `computed` (e.g: `visible: computed(() => state.state.user.isSignedIn)`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I made the object in the array a `ref` too would that work?

Comment: I think it would. AFAIK, when you pass an object to [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) it calls [reactive](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) on it behind the scenes, which means its immediate properties maintain reactivity.

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if menuItems were a computed. It's basically computed from other reactive states (isSignedIn in this case, but also could depend on messages.Signout)

Comment: For a simple explanation, everything you pass to a `ref()` is just the initial value and there is no connection at all. It is just a pure value. If you want to make a connection between two objects, just use `computed`